# Передача переменной из python в js

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Есть у меня два файла (`py` и `js`)

В `py` я использую `selenium` и на самой странице использую `js` скрипты для работы с ней. Но так как внедряемый скрипт на страницу слишком большой, я перенес его в отдельный файл `js`

py:

```
...
driver.execute_script(open('any_script.js').read())
...
```

js:

```
let any_var = "my_var_import";

function any_func(any_var) {...}
...
```

Сам вопрос: Какими способами можно передать переменную из python в javascript (в данном случае в `any_var`)?

Сходу мысли:

1. Делать кашу (все в одном файле).
2. Вносить изменения в `js` файл (редактировать и сразу подставлять нужную переменную)

Answer (score 1):

Через `arguments`

```
driver.excute_script("arguments[0].someCode", variable)
```